# Modify AWS server configuration

Tags: amazon-web-services, cloud

Is it possible to have a Amazon server with the configuration of your choice instead of choosing from there already defined list?

Comment: Yes, you can create custom AMIs. A common tool to do so is called packer. You can also configure instances at launch time via user-data.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no way to customize EC2 instances. It is a main argument used by AWS as all have access to the same resources without discriminations.

Comment: This is true if he means instance types, but I assume he meant the list of available AMIs.